# Workflow error - Record required by this workflow job could not be found

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a basic workflow designed that on completion of a Task - related to an opportunity - the Opportunity is updated.

I get following error

> A record required by this workflow job could not be found.

I am not sure where or what to do next ?

Comment: can you give more detail? what is your workflow doing? how is the workflow triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you receive this error one of the records which are used in the workflow is deleted. Therefore the workflow cannot continue to execute.

This could happen for example

- when using a wait condition (wait until task is completed)
- when the opportunity is deleted and the workflow tries to update it after completion of the task